# Is it safe to reuse the hash object created by the crypto module in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cryptojs, node-crypto

To hash a payload with nodejs, I can use the crypto module and do:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const payload = "abc123";
const hashObj = crypto.createHash('sha256');
const res = hashObj.update(payload).digest('hex');
```

Now say I want to hash a second payload, could I safely reuse the `hashObj` I just instantiated and call `update` and `digest` on it with the new payload? Or do I have to call `createHash` for every payload?

Edit: To clarify, by reuse I mean extending the above code to the following for example:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const payload1 = "abc123";
const payload2 = "def456";
const hashObj = crypto.createHash('sha256');

const res1 = hashObj.update(payload1).digest('hex');
const res2 = hashObj.update(payload2).digest('hex');
```

Comment: note that `.digest()` finalizes the hasher, so you techncially can't even run this code, it'll error out (thankfully =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hasher does not reset, calling `update()` [only adds more data](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hashupdatedata-inputencoding) to the hasher. So this:

```
const res1 = hashObj.update(payload1).digest('hex');
const res2 = hashObj.update(payload2).digest('hex');
```

would assign the hash for `payload1` to `res1`, and the digest for `payload1 + payload2` to `res2`, except for the part where [calling `.digest()` finalizes the hasher](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hashdigestencoding):

> The Hash object can not be used again after hash.digest() method has been called. Multiple calls will cause an error to be thrown.

So for any discrete piece of data, you need a separate hasher, and for any data stream you can `update()` as much as you need to, and then you call `.digest()` once you have everything packed up.